# Gnome 3.26 windows titlebar sizing

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 17.10 on my laptop and still getting used to the "new" DE. I am having troubles setting up window decorations, i.e. title bars are too big for some applications. See [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUy7s.png) to get an idea. Some apps display "normal" size title bar others huge one. Googling around I've found there is per-user CSS file somewhere where to set padding and margin for title bars but, of course, in my install is not there. Should I create it? Isn't there a system wide config?
I am running on a HiDPI display with some font-scaling on but no display scaling, if it matters.

Comment: I think the differences come due to the fact that some applications are still gtk2 and some gtk3 and there are the gnome ones as well. what i did and it helped me greatly was using a theme called minwaita. Not sure if this helps so i Put a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, tried that. It does not  solve the problem as title bars are still quite big...